# Problem with extension method with asp.net web form page code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado

i am creating an extension method to check null datarow with c#, i am trying to use the extension method in my asp.net web form code behind but giving me that the method  IsEmpty doesnot in the current context 
here is the code i am trying

```
 public static class IsNullValidator
    {
        public static bool IsNullEquivalent( this object value)
        {
            return value == null
                   || value is DBNull
                   || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString());
        }
        public static bool IsEmpty( this DataRow row)
        {
            return row == null || row.ItemArray.All(i => i.IsNullEquivalent());
        }
    }
```

and i call it like this

```
DataRow[] row =getRowMethod();
if IsEmpty(row){"do some functionality"}
```

if i changed IsEmpty Signature by removing this keyword to below it works like this

```
   public static bool IsEmpty(  DataRow row)
            {
                return row == null || row.ItemArray.All(i => i.IsNullEquivalent());
            }
   if IsEmpty(row[0]){"do some functionality"}
```

i need to work with this extension to check any datarow and in future to check any datatable 
and can i use the below method to check null datatable

```
 public static bool IsEmptyDatatable (DataTable dt)
    {
        return dt == null || dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r=>r.ItemArray[0]!=null).All(i => i.IsNullEquivalent());
    }
```

Comment: When having issues of this type, I usually go and split the code up over multiple lines, using temproary variables. That way I can debug each opeartion in turn and get proper Exception messages.
There is nothing to worry about regarding performance. The JiT compiler is fully capable of cutting underused variables. If anything it is often *to* good. And  even if there was, code readability and debugability propably just trumps that little difference.

Comment: i am using c# compiler not jit , and the problem in calling the method while coding not at runtime

Comment: The Just in Time Compiler is run over the MSIL by the Runtime, before it ever get's close to the CPU. So it applies here fully. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation

Comment: Ok, I understand ,thank you

Comment: "...the method IsEmpty doesnot in the current context...". I don't understand.

Comment: That's how you don't use Extension method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: ths name 'IsEmpty' does not exist in the current context

Comment: If it's an extension method, you're supposed to call it like `row[0].IsEmpty()`. That's why it's called an extension method, because it extends a type with a new _method_. You just have to make sure you're importing the static class with the proper `using` statement.

Comment: i used it like you mentioned and it works thanks @Jacob , i still face the issue to check null data table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i ended up with the bellow solution ,thank you people ...all what you suggested were helpful

```
 public static bool IsNullEquivalent( this object value)
        {
            return value == null
                   || value is DBNull
                   || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString());
        }
        public static bool IsEmptyDataRow(this  DataRow row)
        {
            return row == null || row.ItemArray.All(i => i.IsNullEquivalent());
        }
        public static bool IsEmptyDatatable (this DataTable dt)
        {
            return dt == null || dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().All(i => i.IsEmptyDataRow());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are "extensions" of a type. In your case you are extending the `DataRow` class. For extension methods you need to have an instance of that class to call it e.g.:

```
DataRow[] row =getRowMethod();

if row.IsEmpty(){"do some functionality"}
```

In the example, the extension method is called on the instance `row` of the `DataRow` class.

If you think of the `this` keyword as saying "this method can be called on an instance of 'this' class" - which in your case is `DataRow`, that might help you to understand it.

Comment: yea as @Jacob mentions i changed it to below if                                
         `row[0].IsEmpty(){"do some functionality"}    `                                                     and it works , but still facing the second issue to check null datatable ,i ended up with this                                                                                                                 
              public static bool IsEmptyDatatable (this DataTable dt)
             `{
               return dt == null || dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().All(i => i.IsEmptyDataRow());
              }`